# Proposition 12.9 - Tu's Introduction to Manifolds

Tags: definition, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

In the following proposition

> Let $s,t$ be $C^{\infty}$ sections of a $C^{\infty}$ vector bundle $\pi : E \to M$ and let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ real valued function on $M$ Then
>
> i) the sum $s + t : M \to E$ defined by
>   $$
> (s + t)(p) = s(p) + t(p) \in E_p, \;\; p \in M
> $$
>   is a $C^{\infty}$ section of $E$.
>
> ii) the product $fs : M \to E$ defined by
>   $$
> (fs)(p) = f(p)s(p) \in E_p, \;\; p \in M$
> $$
>   is a $C^{\infty}$ section of $E$.

I'm having a hard time understanding how this *sum* and *product* are actually defined. I know the vector bundle definition involve the vector space structure. However this is through the locally trivialzing map $\pi$ or the fiber preserving map $\phi$. In the definition both $s$ and $t$ are maps from $M \to E$ and I really struggle to understand how the mentioned operations are actually defined.

Can you clarify?

**My insight**

I'll give you my interpretation. $s,t$ are sections therefore $s(p),t(p)$ belong to the fiber at $p$, name this $E_p$, by definition of tangent bundle, since $E_p = \pi^{-1}(p)$ it has a vector space structure of dimension $r$. It seems apparently that because of this, this is well defined I suppose (can you correct me?). However if I want to actually compute the sum do I need to use the fiber preserving map $\phi$? this indeed would map $E_p$ to $\left\{ p \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^r$ which is a *product bundle*, can I use the vector space structure of the product bundle somehow?

Comment: The definition of section says those choices of local triviality don't matter and lead to the same sum/product.

Comment: Please expound the comment... I cannot follow, the definition I know is a map $s : M \to E$ such that $\pi \circ s = 1_M$ where $(E,M,\pi)$ is a vector bundle. I cannot related your comment with this definition.

Comment: The maps $s,t$ are from $M$ to $E$ not from $E$ to $M$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik fixed, sorry.

Comment: Think locally. On a coordinate chart, via the local trivialisation, you can identify $s$ and $t$ with smooth functions $V \to \mathbb{R}^n$, and $f$ with a function $V \to \mathbb{R}$. You know how to add and multiply such functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer locally the only thing I can see is that $s(p) = (s \circ \psi^{-1})(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ and $t(p) = (t \circ \psi^{-1})(x^1,\ldots x^n)$ if $p \in U$, here $(U,\psi)$ is a chart around $p$. But you can add these in this way regardless if they're sections or not. I'm not 100% sure how the local trivialization is actually used to define the sum/product.

Comment: Suppose $\Lambda$ is a local trivialisation $\Lambda \colon \pi^{-1}(U) \to V \times \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\psi \colon U \to V$ is a coordinate chart. Then you look at $\tilde{s} = p_2\circ \Lambda \circ s \circ \psi^{-1}$ where $p_2 \colon V \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the projection on the second factor. This is a smooth function $V \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Similar for $t$. Then $s+t$ is the section corresponding to $\tilde{s} + \tilde{t}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer With due respect, I feel going to local trivialisation is not necessary...

Comment: You need to use words correctly... Youdid not mention in what sense $\{p\}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is a product bundle... It does not make sense to give a map from a vector space to a product bundle...

Comment: Product bundle I mean $(M \times \mathbb{R}^r, \mathbb{R}^r,\pi)$ where $M$ is a smooth manifold. See example 12.6 here http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf

Comment: So, what is the base space with which $\{p\}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is a product bundle??

Comment: What I meant, but I wrote wrong I admit it, is that $M\times \mathbb{R}^r$ is the product bundle and each $\left\{ p \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^r$ is a vector space, according to that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two maps $s,t:M\rightarrow E$, we attempt to construct a new map $M\rightarrow E$.

Let $m\in M$. Then, $s(m)$ is an element of $E$ and $t(m)$ is an element of $E$.

So, the question now is, given two elements of a manifold $E$, how do you produce another element of the manifold $E$. There seem to be no obvious choice.

But, these $s(m),t(m)$ are in a subset of $E$, namely the fibre of $m$ in $E$, denoted by $E_m$ and defined as $$E_m=\{a\in E:\pi(a)=m\}.$$

By definition, this set $E_m$ has structure of a vector space. So, given two elements of $E_m$, one can consider the sum, sum of two vectors in a vector space, to give an element in $E_m$. So, for $m\in M$, we have $$s(m)+t(m)\in E_m.$$

The map $M\rightarrow E$ defined as $m\mapsto s(m)+t(m)$ for $m\in M$, is denoted by $s+t$, called the sum of $s$ and $t$. One can check that this map$s+t:M\rightarrow E$ is a smooth section of $\pi:E\rightarrow M$.

If this is clear, there should be no confusion regarding product of a section by a real valued smooth map.

Let $\Gamma(E)$ denote the set of sections of $\pi;E\rightarrow M$. We are trying to make this set $\Gamma(E)$ into a $C^{\infty}(M)$-module. For this, we need a notion of sum of two elements of $\Gamma(E)$. Additionally, we need  product of an element of $C^{\infty}(M)$ with an element of $\Gamma(E)$. Is it clear?

Comment: I'm reading through your answer, I updated my question with an **insight** could you tell me if it makes sense? I'm still not sure about the product with a $C^{\infty}$ function, but I'll think about it as exercise.

Comment: Local trivialisation does not come in this situation..

Comment: I've noticed that, because we know by definition the fiber at $p$ is a vector space, is that right? so by defintion there's some $+$ and $\cdot$ defined already, is that right?

Comment: Yes, there is a $+$ defined between two elements of $\Gamma(E)$ and $.$ defined between an element of $C^{\infty}(M)$ and an element of $\Gamma(E)$..

Comment: A silly question why are we sure that the scalar field is actually $C^{\infty}(M)$?

Comment: Firstly it is not scalar “field”.. we are not in the set up of vector spaces to talk about scalar field.... we are in the set up of modules, where “scalars” come from a ring, not necessarily a field... coming to the question, it’s only a choice.. do you have any other rings in mind with which $\Gamma(E)$ becomes a module..??

Comment: But why can we make that choice? I thinks it's important to figure that... If $s(p) \in E_p$, which is a vector space how can we be sure that $f(p)$ is in the scalar field of $E_p$? My only guess is since $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ then $f(p) \in \mathbb{R}$ so $E_p$ has implicitly scalar field $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't think in the vector bundle there's the assumption of real vector space.

Comment: $E_p$ is a real vector space and $f$ is a real valued function... Does that answer your question? If you can recall, there was a mention that there is a vector space isomorphism $E_p\rightarrow \{p\}\times \mathbb{R}^n$.. it may be clear that $ \{p\}\times \mathbb{R}^n$ is a real vector space (if $n$ is even you can also see it as complex vector space, otherwise it’s only a real vector space).. Do you know that one can talk about a vector space isomorphism only when both vector space have same scalar field?? Does it leave any choice other than being real vector space for $E_p$?

Comment: I think I got the picture now.

Comment: Nice. Please buy me a coffee when you see me :D

Comment: Very unlikely I'll see you, but I'd buy you a coffee. Thank you.